# How can I re-run the entire test class of the failed test case using Testng?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to re-run the failed test class of the failed test cases so that I can counter all the previous dependent test cases.

Tried using ITestListener and IRetryAnalyzer, Using onTestFailure class I end in a infinite loop of failure.

I have added this part of code to my onTestFailure class in Listener class-

```
    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    suite.setName("rerunFailedTestClasses");
    XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
    test.setName(result.getMethod().getDescription());
    List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
    classes.add(new XmlClass(result.getTestClass().getName()));
    test.setXmlClasses(classes);
    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
    suites.add(suite);
    TestNG tng = new TestNG();
    tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
    tng.run();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a sample project that can be used to reproduce the problem of infinite loop (You can upload the project into github and share the link of it here). To re-run failed tests, you can just run `testng-failed.xml` again and it should re-run ONLY the failed tests.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan I have added the sample code. I am not looking to re-run failed test cases, I am trying to re-rerun entire test class not just that test case.

Comment: Can we please upload a sample project which gives the complete context? The sample that you shared seems to basically create a new TestNG object and run that. That is NOT going to work because now your test results are going to be completely garbled. It would be good if you could please upload a simple sample project that shows how you are running your test methods, how you are wiring in your listeners etc.,

Answer (score 0):

I'd not recommend re-running full classes automatically for your purpose, although this is unlikely to work properly (i.e. w/o corruption of test results etc).

You can use TestNG IReporter listener to collect a set of classes where at least one test has failed.
Then use the collected classes to create a separate .xml file. It will be similar to the 'testng-failed.xml', but with classes instead of the separate methods.
You can extend the generated file with listeners/parameters if needed.

```
package testlisteners;

import org.testng.*;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class FailedClassesAnalyzer implements IReporter {


@Override
public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
    Set<String> failedClasses = new HashSet<>();
    for (ISuite suite : suites) {
        for (ISuiteResult result : suite.getResults().values()) {
            ITestContext testContext = result.getTestContext();
            if (testContext.getFailedTests().size() > 0) {
                for (ITestResult failedTest : testContext.getFailedTests().getAllResults()) {
                    failedClasses.add(failedTest.getTestClass().getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!failedClasses.isEmpty()) {
        generateXmlFile(failedClasses);
    }
}


private void generateXmlFile(Set<String> failedClasses) {
    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    suite.setName("FailedTestsSuite");

    XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
    test.setName("FailedTests");

    List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String failedClass : failedClasses) {
        classes.add(new XmlClass(failedClass));
    }
    test.setXmlClasses(classes);

    try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("custom-failed-tests.xml")) {
        fileWriter.write(suite.toXml());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```